# File class doesn't recognize Exists or CreateText methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, file-io

A question relating to ASP.NET (4.5.1) MVC 4. I want to create a file and write a line into that file. To my understanding this is very easy i just do the following:

```
public static void Main() 
{
    string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";

    if (!File.Exists(path)) 
    {
        // Create a file to write to. 
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path)) 
        {
           sw.WriteLine("Hello");
           sw.WriteLine("And");
           sw.WriteLine("Welcome");
        }   
    }

    // Open the file to read from. 
    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path)) 
    {
        string s = "";

        while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

But when i call the File class it won't work. It does not know the methods Exists, CreateText.
I don't understand it i did import `System.IO`. So what is the problem?

UPDATE

Found the solution in my project i imported `System.IO` and `System.Web.MVC`.
The solution is to call the File class with the full path like so:

```
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path)) 
    {
        // Create a file to write to. 
        using (StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.CreateText(path)) 
        {
           sw.WriteLine("Hello");
           sw.WriteLine("And");
           sw.WriteLine("Welcome");
        }   
    }
```

Comment: `.File`property of what? What is that?

Comment: Can you post your usings?

Comment: `File` is a **class** within the `System.IO` namespace ([msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx)).

Comment: @Styxxy: he mentioned he already imported the `System.IO` namespace.

Comment: @Styxxy We know that, he's most likely got a conflict with a class in an existing namespace.

Comment: Just found the answer i also imported 'System.Web.MVC' so i had to specify that i wanted to user 'System.IO.File'

Comment: @Abbas: he is talking about a property `File` but `File` in the code he showed, is a **class**.

Comment: @Styxxy, I think he meant class instead of property. If he imported the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace, he might be conflicting with the `File()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem :** I suspect that you have different class in your Project with the name of `File`.
so it is referring to that `File` instead of `System.IO.File`.

**Solution :** i'd suggest you to use fully qualified namespace to access the `File` class from `System.IO` to avoid the ambiguity as below:

```
if(!System.IO.File.Exists("path"))
{


}
```

Comment: Just added found the answer. But your the first to post the right answer. So i will mark it correct.